# How to set selected item or value for listbox in WPF from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, listbox

I have listbox and i need to set its selected value from code. It is not getting selected given value.I am working on WPF application. Please help me with code.
Following is my code:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lbCheque" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,191,0,0" 
      Width="200" Height="210" SelectionChanged="lbCheque_SelectionChanged" >
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                 <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
             </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Code behind:

```
lbCheque.SelectedItem = "abcd";
```

Comment: what is the bound ItemsSource type? Is it List<string>?

Comment: Not sure how you mean "set its selected value from code". Do you mean you want to add a ListItem from your code-behind into your current ListBox?

Comment: I need to set selected value from ListItems

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="lbCheque" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,191,0,0" 
          Width="200" Height="210" >
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>

        <Button 
            Grid.Column="1"
            Content="Select" 
            Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbCheque.ItemsSource = new List<string> {"aa","bb","cc" };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbCheque.SelectedItem = "bb";
    }
```

This relies on the fact that strings are a bit strange and all strings "bb" are the same object.  With a more complicated objet I'd need to get a reference to a specific instance or override equals in the class.